# Template or function overload for generic argument

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a function which takes three arguments

```
void replace(const string, const string, string*) ;
```

My problem is the second argument which I'd like to rewrite so it can be either a string or a Path object (from the Boost Filesystem library, but really any object that can be treated as a string should do) so I don't have to convert paths to strings all over the place.

I know I can overload the function and make two implementations, that's what I do now so I have two implementations of the same function:

```
void replace(const string, const string, string*) ;
void replace(const string, const path, string*) ;
```

But that doesn't seem very elegant, even if the second one just converts the path to a string and calls the first (so not much code duplication). I've tried using templates instead, like this:

```
template <class T>
void replace(const string, const T, string*) ;
```

But the implementation of the function requires that it is a string, so if it is given a path it needs to be converted to a string within the function, which I'm not sure how to do or if it's even a good thing to do.

To further complicate matters, in the future I might want to expand the function so it can also take a set of strings or a set of paths instead of just one string/path as the second argument.

What is the best way to handle all this? Is there no better way than having more than one implementation of the same function?

Comment: Overloads are probably the correct approach. Also you probably should take these arguments by const reference. Also, pointers are ugly and non-const references are better.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus What do you mean by non-const reference here? I thought that's what I was doing (assuming you're speaking of the third argument)

Comment: The third argument is a pointer. References are made with an ampersand: `void replace(const std::string&, const std::string&, std::string&);`

Comment: I thought there was no difference between the two in function arguments.

Comment: Of course there is. References are not pointers, and pointers are not references.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Suggesting that the non-const references are better is wrong. This is purely subjective and a personal preference... there is no right or wrong (I could argue that an object with the syntax of a value should not behave like a pointer... although I myself go with references unless I also accept NULL as a possible value... but again, that is personal preference).

Comment: @Samaursa: No, they're objectively better. The only use for a pointer argument is when passing `nullptr` is a valid choice. But then again, might also use `boost::optional` and not have to remember to create the pointer at the call site.

Comment: As it is now it takes a reference to a string, it modifies it in place instead of returning it, that's what I want. So what's the benefit of your suggestion?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Not when I am deep in a function and forget that the object is actually behaving like a pointer and the changes are not local any more... personal preference, some people like it one way, some the other way.

Comment: @Samaursa: Er, what? References are not "behaving like pointers". If you can't remember the type of your variables, then use an IDE or train your memory. Or write shorter functions.

Either way, I'm evacuating from this discussion, have fun.

Comment: @ADCoon "As it is now it takes a reference to a string" - No, it takes a pointer to a string. He is suggesting that, as an alternative to  what you have, it take a reference to a string instead.

Comment: @Rob Well, I pass it a reference. I pass it something like `&some_string` which is a reference, yes? I pass it not the value but just the reference, so it operates on the global object that I reference not a local copy. As far as I can tell the effect should be exactly the same, so what makes one better than the other?

Comment: @ADCoon - No, `&some_string` is not a reference. It is a pointer. As to your question, "what makes one better than the other?" I never said one was better than the other, CatPlusPlus did. I have no opinion on that.

Comment: @Rob OK, pointer then (though it uses the reference syntax of the & sign?) But what is the difference? Why is one better?

Comment: @ADCoon  No, it doesn't use reference syntax, it uses the address-of operator. As to your question, "what makes one better than the other?" I never said one was better than the other, CatPlusPlus did. I have no opinion on that.

Comment: @Rob Ah, fair enough. But is there a difference other than a technical distinction? I mean, whether it's called a "pointer to something" or a "reference to something" seems pretty arbitrary to me. Both supposedly just contain a memory address rather than a value, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloaded functions is the best approach for your use case.

I usually go by the following rules:

- If you want to perform *same actions* on *different data types* then prefer templates.
- If you want to perform *different actions* on *different data types* then prefer function overloading.

Your use case falls in the second category.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Maybe I'm too used to dynamically typed languages. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a function like:

```
void replace(const string s, const path p, string* ss) {
    replace(s, convert_to_string(path), ss);
}
```

Let the optimizer decide how it should handle that. What's not elegant about it? Your template method will do the same thing, it'll just be more complicated.

Comment: That's what I do right now. It just seems like it would be nicer with only one generic function, even if all but one of them are just wrappers.